# How AngularJS returned value convert to integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using a nested form and AngularJS, and I have this on my code.

```
#app/view/customer_templates/edit.html.erb
<%= f.simple_fields_for :customer_template, @customer.customer_template.build, child_index: '{{$index}}' do |t| %>
  <%= t.select :field_type_id, options_from_collection_for_select(FieldType.all, :id, :name, '{{customer_template.field_type_id}}') %>      
<% end %>
```

My select is working but not getting the current data of `field_type_id`.

`{{customer_template.field_type_id}}` from angular, is returning the right data but it is a string, when I tried to convert this to integer like `{{customer_template.field_type_id}}.to_i`, the result is **0**. I tried also to pass this to a variable and converted it, but I am getting same result.

I also tried this `{{parseInt(customer_template.field_type_id)}}`, and in my angularjs `$scope.parseInt = parseInt` but have no luck.

This is my problem, below.

[image]

I must have 1-Checkbox, 2-Dropdown (Yes/No), and 2-Textbox, can you help me with this? I am a noob in AngularJS. My only problem is the value, I will put inside `options_from_collection_for_select`. If I can put an integer, it is working.

Comment: Please show us static html, not ruby template. This is important to see data structure. Where the data comes from?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the short hand conversion in javascript?

```
{{+customer_template.field_type_id}}
```

And in your controller like this:

```
$scope.parseInt = +parseInt;
```